# Why does Google use the icon from the manifest file instead of the favicon in the search results?

Tags: seo, favicon, google-search-console

In my website I have a small (16x16) favicon.ico and a completely different image used as an icon in the web manifest file. If I check with the Google favicon tool ([www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=example.com](http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=example.com)) the 16x16 image is the favicon but for the 24x24 image is the one from the manifest which seems like the one use in search results even if it is rendered in 24x24. How can I force Google search results to show the favicon.ico in their results?

Comment: You can't force them to do something, but you can create conditions so that they visualize what you would like. Since the information you provide is scarce, I recommend you review the documentation and their requirements: [Define a favicon to show in search results](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/favicon-in-search)